# jquery mobile buttons on desktop browser

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

is it possible to add the jquery mobile look and feel of some buttons onto a desktop browser?

I included the jquery mobile css and js files and when I click the button, it's doing some behind the scenes stuff and not actually taking me to my destination.  When I remove the JS (the cause of the strange behavior on the desktop), the button, as expected, doesn't get rendered the way I want it to.

Ideally, I'd like to just see the pure css and simplified JS that's rendering the button so that I can just add it to my desktop layout, and if that's an option to do somehow, that would work for my purposes.

I really don't want to have to dig through all of the jquery mobile js files and figure out what is going on there to piece this together though.

how can I just pare out what I need to have my buttons rendered on the desktop with the same look/feel as the mobile device w/o the mobile device functionality.

**Edit for answer below:**

this is what I"m calling now on my desktop page:

```
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/jquery.mobile.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/mobile/themes/LS.min.css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and calling the button like this:

```
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="/home/foldit" data-icon="star">
                Fold It
        </a>
```

this is showing a textual representation of my button, not rendering the button.  the only file I didn't include from the package is the "custom theme" css file because I figured that my theme should replace that. (the LS.min.css file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can rebuild jQuery mobile framework and use only wanted modules.

Go here: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ and select only what you want.

```
*We’ve decoupled all of our plugins and have a clear dependency map which allows us to offer the download builder tool (Alpha) to let you build the leanest package possible.*
```

It is only usable with jQM 1.1.1 up to 1.2

Comment: sweet this looks really promising.  any idea what I need to select to just have my buttons rendered?  I want to be able to use my custom layout.  an example of a button that I"m using is like this: <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="/home/foldit" data-icon="star" data-transition="fade">

Comment: Select only Buttons: Link-based, it will automatically select all dependencies.

Comment: did that.  See my OP for the files I'm including, and how I"m asking the button to be rendered.  It's just showing a textual link.

Comment: if I add the jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js file it renders the button, like I'd like, but it puts me back to where I was before, the behavior of the button is trying to use jquery mobileish stuff.